# How to go to 'else if' loop after 'if' condition is sucessfully entered

Tags: php

Is there any way to go to the `else if` body after the `if` condition is sucessfully entered?
Is there any way to go to the `else if` body after the `if` condition is sucessfully entered?

```
    if ($axisX == $axisXOne) {   /* Main IF Statement */
            if($axisY =='0' && $axisYOne == '1') { $second = '2';}
        else if($axisY =='0' && $axisYOne == '2') { $second = '1';}
        else if($axisY =='1' && $axisYOne == '0') { $second = '2';}
        else if($axisY =='1' && $axisYOne == '2') { $second = '0';}
        else if($axisY =='2' && $axisYOne == '0') { $second = '1';}
        else if($axisY =='2' && $axisYOne == '1') { $second = '0';}

            if (($_POST['button'.$axisX.$second] == null) && ($curVal != $axisX.$second)){ /* Inner IF Statement */
             echo $axisX.$second; 
             }
    }   
    else if ($axisY == $axisYOne) {  /* Main ELSE IF statement */
        if($axisX =='0' && $axisXOne == '1') { $second = '2';}
        else if($axisX =='0' && $axisXOne == '2') { $second = '1';}
        else if($axisX =='1' && $axisXOne == '0') { $second = '2';}
        else if($axisX =='1' && $axisXOne == '2') { $second = '0';}
        else if($axisX =='2' && $axisXOne == '0') { $second = '1';}
        else if($axisX =='2' && $axisXOne == '1') { $second = '0';}
            if($_POST['button'.$second.$axisY] == null) {/* Inner IF Statement */
              echo $second.$axisY;
             }
    }
    else if ($xAxis == $yAxis && $xAxisOne == $yAxisOne) {  /* other Main ELSE IF Statement*/
            if($comVal[0] == '00' && $comVal[1] == '11') { $diagon = '22';}
        else if($comVal[0] == '00' && $comVal[1] == '22') { $diagon = '11';}
        else if($comVal[0] == '11' && $comVal[1] == '00') { $diagon = '22';}
        else if($comVal[0] == '11' && $comVal[1] == '22') { $diagon = '00';}
        else if($comVal[0] == '22' && $comVal[1] == '00') { $diagon = '11';}
        else if($comVal[0] == '22' && $comVal[1] == '11') { $diagon = '00';}
            if($_POST['button'.$diagon] == null) {
            echo $diagon;
            }
    }
```

If Main IF Statement evaluates true and Inner IF Statement evalautes false then go to Main ELSE IF ladder. If Main IF Statement evaluates              true and Inner IF Statement evalautes true then stop loop . If Main IF Statement evaluates false, directly go to Main ELSE IF Statement

If Main ELSE IF Statement evaluates true and Inner IF Statement evalautes false then go to Main ELSE IF ladder. If Main ElSE IF Statement evaluates true and Inner IF Statement evalautes true ,then stop loop .If Main ELSE IF Statement evaluates false, directly go to other Main ELSE IF Statements

Comment: put the code you would otherwise repeat into a subroutine and call it from both places. Give it a good name.

Comment: I second Thilo's recommendation - you almost certainly need a subroutine.

Comment: Your variable name is horrible.

Comment: @all- Sorry, for using bad variable name.Its just an demo naming

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$success = true;

if($a == $Xaxis && $b == $yaxis) {
    $zAxis    = $Xaxis + $yaxis;
    $success  = $Xaxis != $zAxis;
}
if( ($b == $Xaxis && $a == $yaxis) || !$success) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Spaghetti code. Better to put the code you would otherwise repeat into a subroutine and call it from both places.

Comment: I would do that, but I don't know if the asker has PHP >= 5.3 or not. They only specify PHP 5.

Comment: Also seems to not work correctly (as a result of the spaghetti-ness). It will now enter the `stuff here` block if no condition matches at all, because $success is initially false)

Comment: @Kolink - +1 for being clever and inventive ... but one should never do it in production code.  "subroutine" is really the only answer for "the same thing, but needs to be done in two different places".  IMHO...

Comment: @Kolink- Thanks for your answer, but when first IF statement evalutes true, then we dont need to go on second IF statement even if it evaluates true. I am using PHP > 5.3 and edited my code.Please have a look.